# Uniform Convergence of $f_n(x)= \sin(x+\frac 1n)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Prove that $\sin(x+(1/n)) \rightarrow \sin x$ uniformly on $R$ using Mean Value Theorem.

I'm not sure how to go about this. Because the problem asks to use MVT, I tried taking the derivative of the function in order to find the supremum and use that to show that the supremum was less than some epsilon to prove uniform convergence, but I am having a hard time.

Comment: What did you try? $\cos (x)$ is bounded by $1$ and it is surely sent to $0$ by the $\frac{1}{n}$ term

Comment: Can you think about the picture first before attempting the proof?  What does the graph of $\sin(x + \frac{1}{n})$ look like in comparison to $\sin{x}$?

Answer (score 4):

For all $x\in \mathbb R$,

$$\sin\left(x +\frac 1n \right) - \sin x = \sin' (y)\left( x +\frac 1n  -x\right)$$

for some $y\in (x, x+\frac 1n)$ by the MVT. Note that the right hand side is always smaller than $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: beat me by 10 seconds, sigh +1

Answer (score 0):

Since $|\sin'(x)| \le 1$ for all $x$, we have
$| \sin(x+ {1\over n})-\sin x| \le {1 \over n}$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

For all $n \geq 1$, by mean-value theorem we have
$$
\Big| \sin \Big( x + \frac{1}{n} \Big) - \sin x \Big| \leq \Big( x + \frac{1}{n} - x \Big) \sup_{x < t < x + \frac{1}{n}}| \cos t| 
\leq
\frac{1}{n}
$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$;
if $\varepsilon > 0$, then $n \geq \Big\lceil \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \Big\rceil + 1$ only if $\frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$;
we have thus proved this: for every $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $n \geq \Big\lceil \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \Big\rceil + 1$ only if 
$$
\Big| \sin \Big( x + \frac{1}{n} \Big) - \sin x \Big| < \varepsilon
$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$